# Is the man Paul talks to in the south desert meant to be Korba?

Tags: dune, dune-2024

Towards the end of the 2024 Dune, Part 2, Paul talks to a man about his grandmother who is later in some other scenes of the battle at the end.

Is this meant to be [Korba](https://dune.fandom.com/wiki/Korba)?

It seems like a lot of screen time for an extra. I couldn’t see the credits.

Comment: Korba is not listed in the credits on IMDB; https://m.imdb.com/title/tt15239678/fullcredits/cast?ref_=m_ttfc_3

Comment: I have not seen the film. Did they have any lines? If not then the credits won't help.

Comment: Thanks for the imdb did not think to look there. Appears to be listed as huge fighter https://m.imdb.com/name/nm11931823/?ref_=m_ttfcd_cl46